# Assigning the value of an array variable to itself?

Tags: java, concurrency, volatile, memory-visibility

I have this simple piece of code.

```
class A {
    static volatile String[] a = new String[9];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                    while (a[i] == null);
                    System.out.println(a[i]);
                }
            }
        }.start();

        a[0] = "The";
        zzz();
        a[1] = "quick";
        zzz();
        a[2] = "brown​";
        zzz();
        a[3] = "fox";
        zzz();
        a[4] = "jumped";
        zzz();
        a[5] = "over";
        zzz();
        a[6] = "the";
        zzz();
        a[7] = "lazy";
        zzz();
        a[8] = "cat";
        zzz();
    }

    public static void zzz() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(300);
        } catch (Exception e) {}
        a=a;
    }
}
```

It outputs what I'd expect:

```
$ javac A.java && java A
The
quick
brown​
fox
jumped
over
the
lazy
cat
```

The strange thing is the `a=a` in `zzz()`. It doesn't seem to change anything when I take it out. Why is it there?

Comment: It doesn't do anything. It was probably left there to add a breakpoint.

Comment: Does assigning to a volitle publish it for other threads?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only reason I can think of is that the person who wrote that code understood that only the array is volatile but not its content and added `a = a` to enforce visibility of the writes performed on the array items.

> It doesn't seem to change anything when I take it out.

The fact that it still works on your machine with your JVM does not mean that it would work on another machine with a different JVM. In theory, removing the `a = a;` statement could lead to a never-ending while loop.

---

Side note

I would have thought that the Java Memory Model (JMM) could allow a JVM to ignore that statement, the same way that a `synchronized(new Object())` can be ignored.

It seems however that [it is not the case*](http://jeremymanson.blogspot.co.uk/2009/06/volatile-arrays-in-java.html):

> You may have noticed that I did provide a way of getting a volatile write above with just arrays: **by writing out a self-reference**.

<sub>*Jeremy Manson is one of the authors of the JMM.</sub>

Comment: I was considering your last part, though I am curious about rules for removing dead code like this of a volatile variable.

Comment: @JohnVint It seems it is not the case - updating.

Comment: yes +1, the most important part I find in the blog is `This definitely does provide the volatile write. However, what good does it do you? The virtue of a volatile write is that a corresponding read can detect that it happened, and do something based on the new value. `

Comment: @JohnVint And in the ops code we have both so the program can't have an inifinite loop.